# Make jquery table clickable

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I created a jquery table that contains data from mysql table and I need to make it clickable because I want to make a modal appear when it is clicked. The problem is that the click vent does not work in jquery table. This is my jquery table:

```
$('#btnLoadAttendance').click(function(){
var dept = $('#cmbdept').val();
if(dept == "SEWING")
{
    var dLine = $('#cmbline').val();
    var dSection = $('#cmbsection').val();
    console.log(dept+', '+dLine+', '+dSection);
    var formdata = {dept:dept,section:dSection,line:dLine};
}
else
{
    var dLine = '';
    var dSection = '';
    console.log(dept);
    var formdata = {dept:dept};
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo site_url('tms/loadAttendance');?>",
    data:formdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.emplist[0]);
        var tr;
        $('#tblAttendance tbody').empty();
        $.each(data.emplist,function(i,item){
            if(item.Active == '1')
            {
                var status = 'Active';
            }
            else
            {
                var status = 'Resigned';
            }

            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td><a href='#'>Edit</a></td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+item.EmpID+"</td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+item.Lastname+', '+item.Firstname+', '+item.Middlename+"</td>");
            tr.append("<td>"+status+"</td>");
            $('#tblAttendance').append(tr);
        });
    },
});
});
```

And this is the click event I am using:

```
$(function(){
$('#tblAttendance tbody td').click(function(){
    console.log('You clicked');
});
});
```

I already googled for solutions but they gave me mismatch answers..

Comment: Maybe you should put selector for `tr`, not `td`?

Comment: I tried but nothing changes. I also tried putting only tr td but same results.

Comment: `tbody td` will select all `td`s in `tbody`. Your `td`s are in `tr`, not `tbody`. At least they should be.

Comment: Could you give your generated code? Run the code in browser, inspect it and paste to us your generated table in HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('#tblAttendance tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
     console.log('You clicked');
});
```

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer. Glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

You are using selector for non-dynamic created elements. You should use selector for dynamically created, like this:

```
$('#tblAttendance').on('click', 'tbody ...', function(){
    //your code here..
});
```

Or just:

```
$(document).on('click', 'tbody ...', function(){
    //your code here..
});
```

Trick is to select some non-dynamic parent element, and in `.on()` function insert one which needs to have on-click handler.